# Logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

I want to categorize 20 responses from the BBC survey into average ability (chance level) and greater ability. I read somewhere that 25% above chance is no longer chance. Is it appropriate to use 12.5% above 50% (62.5%) as the category "greater ability" for logistic regression? Have I calculated this correctly?

I am using the BBC survey "Spot the fake Smile" as the responses for ability.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/science/humanbody/mind/index_surveys.shtml

I have 20 predictor variables to create a composite variate of personality.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that your data consists of 20 of pictures, you want to categorize people with respect to the proportion of pictures the respondent classified correctly as a fake smile.

First comment. If you have 20 pictures, does it make sense to look at cut-off values like 12.5%? Think of the possible outcomes; someone could classify 0 pictures out of 20 correctly (0%), 1 picture out of 20 correctly (5%), 2 pictures out of 20 correctly (10%), etc. So 12.5% can never occur in your data.

Second comment. Those cut-offs are just arbitrary rules of thumb. If you want something more rigorous you can look [irt](/questions/tagged/irt) models.

Third comment. Why do you want to classify them, why not just use the proportion or number of correctly classified pictures?